# Session state server custom timeouts for users

Tags: asp.net, azure, redis, session-state-server

I want to use a SessionStateServer Redis in Azure Cache. My problem is I want to set a custom timeouts for our users but it always takes the default value.

How do I specify custom timeout values for our users ?

```html
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="20">
     <providers>
       <add type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" name="MySessionStateStore" host="host" port="6380" accessKey="pass" ssl="true" throwOnError="true" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="0" databaseId="0" applicationName="xxxDev" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" />
     </providers>
   </sessionState>
```

Comment: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx does setting <sessionstate timeout="customevalue" not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This same bug was reported here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx#comments

It is fixed in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.1.0